# How can humans read this correctly?

Tags: language

Surprisingly, the image below is readable to humans. It is not a specific language. How is this possible?

[image]

> 1N73LL1G3NC3 15 7H3 4B1L17Y 70 4D4P7 70 CH4NG3.
>   573PH3N H4WK1NG

Comment: It's called leetspeak: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet

Comment: It is a very specific language. It is called **English**. It has been the fact that it uses non-standard symbols for some of the characters doe not make it "not English" all of a sudden.

Comment: You can read that?

Comment: @CodyGray I read it as if it was using a standard English alphabet, this is likely due to years of reading such things.

Comment: @CodyGray It took me a second but just look at the first word as a whole instead of character by character, once you get the first word the rest just fall into place.

Comment: Just take off your glasses and squint. Perfectly readable. Of course, you have to be intelligent, or you can't adapt to variations, like this one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is related to neurosciences rather than  UX. This question could be moved to https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @CodeGray My native language is not English. I had difficulties reading that text *after* having read oerkelens' comment. *Before* having read that comment I thought: "What kind of message is the question asking about?" This shows you that you cannot read such messages if you don't speak the language the message is written in very well. (D43 GL4UB3 1CH ZUM1ND357)

Comment: It's useful to understand how the mind works: "what you see is what you think you'll see" ( ie stored information in the mind overrides actual visual data ).  Which is a useful insight when you can't understand why users don't see the button which is sitting in front of their face.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**This is psychology**

Humans are the World's Best Pattern-Recognition Machines.
Quite simply, humans are amazing pattern-recognition machines. They have the ability to recognize many different types of patterns - and then transform these  "recursive probabilistic fractals" into concrete, actionable steps. If you've ever watched a toddler learn words and concepts, you can almost see the brain neurons firing as the small child starts to recognize patterns for differentiating between objects. [Read more](http://bigthink.com/endless-innovation/humans-are-the-worlds-best-pattern-recognition-machines-but-for-how-long).

[Research article from cambridge university](https://www.mrc-cbu.cam.ac.uk/people/matt.davis/cmabridge/) states:

> 1. Psycholinguistic evidence on scrambled letters in reading
> 2. It deosn't mttaer in waht oredr the ltteers in a wrod are, the olny iprmoatnt tihng is taht the frist and lsat ltteer be at the rghit pclae... it doesn't matter in what order the letters in a word are, the only important thing is that the first and last letter be at the right place
> 3. the rset can be a toatl mses and you can sitll raed it wouthit porbelm... the rest can be a total mess and you can still read it without problem
> 4. Tihs is bcuseae the huamn mnid deos not raed ervey lteter by istlef, but the wrod as a wlohe... This is because the human mind does not read every letter by itself by the word as a whole.

[Other article](https://www.mrc-cbu.cam.ac.uk/people/matt.davis/cmabridge/)

Comment: For your last point: we don't just read whole words - we also read sequences of them (normally up to 5) in order to do further recognition and error correction.

Comment: Yes agree, we humans recognize patterns

Comment: "the only important thing is that the first and last letter be at the right place"  
uoiinnnnccvg, ueeirrttsncd slbnmcraig is piaoelbmtrc. I'd say it becomes a lot harder the more the letters are rearranged.

Comment: "_humans are amazing pattern-recognition machines_" -- very true, but sometimes we're _too_ good at it ... patterns in ink-blots, faces in clouds. The brain doesn't like true randomness and will often "find" a pattern that isn't there.

Comment: I got to the word 'toatl' in the third point before I realised the second point was jumbled.

Comment: Note that the Cambridge research article debunks some of the points in that scrambled text that was widely circulated some years ago, specifically it says point 2) is "clearly wrong".

Comment: Agree we cannot really identify with just first and last letters .. good catch

Comment: @TripeHound It's a notable enough phenomenon that there's a word for it: [pareidolia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareidolia).

Comment: Are you sure this is psychology? It seems more about actual physical function of the brain (neurology) and not really about behaviours.

Comment: actuallyyy yeah its realted to brain and it's function.Interestingly there may be some neurotransmitters implicated in our ability to recognize and respond to patterns. But i think it leans somewhere towards psycology

Comment: More than 50% of this answer is taken up by a quote that is plain **false**, and which is debunked by the link you provide. In fact, your wording implies that the link *supports* the quote, rather than debunking it. Please change this.

Comment: "Humans are the World's Best Pattern-Recognition Machines." Proof? Who's to say cats aren't better? Or dogs? Or octopuses? Or...

Comment: @ObliviousSage Aporia Deli? Oh, that's two words. Hmm...

Comment: @Joren I got "unconvincing" right away somehow.  No idea what the rest is.

Comment: @JMac The last word is "problematic". The two intermediate words are harder to guess for me.

Comment: @AlexR Unconvincing, unrestricted scrambling is problematic

Answer (score 18):

**Because our brains  are highly adept at recognizing patterns.**

To speed things up a bit, our brains gather a lot of data in one go, and attempt to descipher it in stages. The first stage is very quick - it takes the overall shape of a word (high emphasis on start and end letters) and matches it to a word it already knows.

As such, 3 and E are alike, but "flipped", so our brain can adapt to that difference. Same for *A* and 4. 5 and S. T and 7. O and 0. Some of these are obvious, others slightly less so.

It's the same tihng taht lets us raed tihs lien wtihuot too mcuh effrot!

**In** fact, you didn't notice that in thise **Iine**, I swapped the capital i and lowercase L's around on the emphasised words... it's the same principle!

Also, I'm pretty sure that's in English - it's just got some letters swapped out for numbers!

Comment: I don't know if you shuffled the last letter of "line" intentionally, but it works extra well because I read it and stumbled for a split second on that word.

Comment: @Erik also the fact that misspelling is a word in its own right causes a pause.

Comment: @ChrisH now we all understand dyslexia.

Comment: If the image in the OP is English, then the result of enciphering English text using a substitution cipher is English. And if your penultimate paragraph is English, then the result of enciphering English text using a transposition cipher is English. How strong a cipher must be used on English text for you not to claim that the ciphertext is English?

Comment: @RosieF I would argue that the image in the OP isn't really a substitution cipher (or maybe a trivial one at most) in the normal sense because that the symbols being substituted are intentionally visually similar to the originals. So it's more like bad handwriting or a weird font.

Answer (score 4):

We have evolved to recognize patterns, to be able to apply a greater amount of detail to something where we don't have a lot of accurate detail, by making assumptions.

For example, we recognize faces at a distance because we can abstract it away to a very basic structure with very little detail.  This is why a colon and a parenthesis can look like a happy or a sad face (depending on which parenthesis you use.)  `:)  :(`  The two dots are close enough to our abstract idea of eyes, and the curved line is close enough to our abstract idea of a mouth.  I could add a dash and that would be close enough to our abstract idea of a nose.  `:-)`

The more we add details, the less our brain has to make corrections and assumptions, so if someone paints a face using shading and color, then we can see a face in deliberately placed brushstrokes, or in our digital age, in thousands (or even millions) of deliberately colored pixels.

This is similar to a thing called *pareidolia* which is an effect that we're constantly being fooled by.  It's how we confuse ourselves into thinking we see a face in objects that are obviously not meant to have faces (for example, a famous rock formation on Mars)

[image: Mars Face]

We developed this technique due to our tribal history.  Being able to recognize faces from a distance in low light allowed us, as hunter/gatherers to recognize fellow tribe members or potential unfamiliar humans who might be a threat.  Being able to make this distinction helped human tribes survive and keep their tribe secure, thus the trait passed on.

This ability developed as our intelligence and ability to recognize patterns developed.  It became more and more sophisticated over time, especially once we started doing art.  We could draw a rough shape on a cave wall and recognize an animal or a hunter.  The shape was "good enough" to fit the brain's rough idea of what said animal or hunter should look like.

So when we see writing like

```
1N73LL1G3NC3 15 7H3 4B1L17Y 70 4D4P7 70 CH4NG3.
573PH3N H4WK1NG
```

Our brains know to expect letters and therefore it looks at the numbers and picks the letter whose abstract shape most resembles the number that's in it's place, swaps them, and then forms the words

```
INTELLIGENCE IS THE ABILITY TO ADAPT TO CHANGE.
STEPHEN HAWKING
```

It can do this because 1 is close enough to I.  7 is close enough to T.  0 is close enough to O and so on and so forth.

So thank your hunter-gatherer ancestors for this ability.  They gave us the foundations for 1337speak, impressionism, and pixels.

Wikipedia on pareidolia:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareidolia